# How to delete specific days of week from MATLAB timeseries or financial timeseries objects?

Tags: matlab, time-series

How to delete specific days of week (Mondays for instance) from MATLAB timeseries or financial timeseries objects?

Comment: Delete specific days of weeks = replace by NaN value to represent a missing data value?

Comment: Well, that will do, but how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is with what I came up with.

```
function [ ret_fts ] = deleteWeekDays( fts, dayName )
tsz = size(fts);
sz = tsz(1);
for i=1:sz,
    mat=fts2mat(fts(i),1);
    [dnum, dnam] = weekday(mat(1));
    if dnam==dayName
        fts(i) = NaN;
    end
end
ret_fts=fts;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas, but only remove a specific date, not a specific day of week, it doesn't look like there's any clever the way to do so, so you might have to generate the date vector to delete yourself:

```
% Set time series
ts = timeseries([3 6 8 0 10 3 6 8 0 10 3 6 8 0 10 3 6 8 0 10 3 6 8 0 10])
ts.Data
tsc = tscollection(ts);
tsc.TimeInfo.Units = 'days';
tsc.TimeInfo.StartDate = '10/27/2005 07:05:36';

% Plot
ts.DataInfo.Interpolation = tsdata.interpolation('zoh');
tsc1.TimeInfo.Format='DD:HH:MM';
figure
plot(ts)

% Change the date-string format of the time vector.
tsc.TimeInfo.Format = 'mm/dd/yy';
tscTime = getabstime(tsc)

% Spot the days you're interested in, get indices and replace them by NaN
% in ts.
dayToDelete = '11/11/05';
idx = strcmp(tscTime, dayToDelete);
ts.Data(idx) = NaN;

% Plot after deleting the specific date
ts.DataInfo.Interpolation = tsdata.interpolation('zoh');
figure
plot(ts)
```